# AngularJs Directive - Accessing attributes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I love angularjs, but I get so confused with directives lol.

I have the following:

```
//postcode grabber
app.directive('postcodes',
    function ($rootScope, $http) {
        return function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('change', function () {
                var targetSuburb = scope.$eval(attrs.targetSuburb);
                alert(targetSuburb);
                var modal_element = angular.element('#myModal');
                var ctrl = modal_element.controller();
                var url = '/postage/postcodes/?suburb=' + element.val();
                ctrl.setModal(url);
                modal_element.modal('show');
            });
        };
    });
```

This my HTML:

```
<input type="text" class='form-control' ng-model="model.suburb" postcodes id='ca_suburb' target-suburb='ca_suburb' target-state='ca_state' target-postcode='ca_postcode'>
```

The alert is always "undefined" - Is there something I'm missing to be able to access the attributes correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get what is typed in, you should access via scope like this

```
alert(scope.model[attrs.targetSuburb]);
```

where `attrs.targetSuburb` should be the field name and it should be set like this since you define the model to be `model.suburb`

```
target-suburb='suburb'
```

Comment: re-used component, it's not always scope.model.suburb - thanks tho!

Comment: @BenKilah Updated. basically you need to tell the directive what is the field name

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the value of the model then

```
app.directive('postcodes', function ($rootScope, $http) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            element.bind('change', function () {
                console.log(controller.$viewVaue)

                var modal_element = angular.element('#myModal');
                var ctrl = modal_element.controller();
                var url = '/postage/postcodes/?suburb=' + element.val();
                ctrl.setModal(url);
                modal_element.modal('show');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fT4qe/)

If you are looking to alert `ca_suberb` then just use

alert(attrs.targetSuburb);

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yYqFN/)

If `ca_suberb` is a scope property then your code is working fine

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yYqFN/)

Comment: @BenKilah what do you actually want to fetch here?

Comment: @BenKilah if you want the typed value then use `ngModel` as updated above - it will give you the value of the binded field

Comment: thanks! - where does controller.$viewVaue come from? couldn't find it in the docs.